# Solution for Django model composite foreign keys

Tags: python, django, sqlalchemy

I’m working with two models in Django: Order and OrderItems. I want to establish a one-to-one relationship between them using two columns instead of the usual single column.

I’m aware of solutions like SQL Alchemy’s ForeignKeyConstraint and the django-composite-foreignkey package, but I’d prefer not to use ForeignKeyConstraint and the latter isn’t compatible with Django 4.0. Is there an alternative solution available for creating a composite foreign key that references two columns in Django 4.0?

```
class Orders(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager()
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    order_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    --------> here it should reference with two columns ( id and department_id ) 
orderItem = models.ForeignKey('OrderCustomers', on_delete=models.PROTECT, db_column='order_item_id', to_field='id')
    order_item_id = models..CharField(max_length=255)
    department_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_at = DateTimeWithoutTZField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = DateTimeWithoutTZField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.order_id
```

Comment: Django does not work with composite primary keys or foreign keys, and normally is not necessary anyway.

Comment: I have a legacy db that was created by php laravel and it has duplicates, single column does not suffice, looking for neat solutions.

Comment: personally I often think that keeping a legacy database only makes it worse. Yes, moving to a new database and syncing the data is hard, but eventually often better than keeping stacking up all sorts of tricks that eventually make it worse. There are good reasons to only allow one primary key, for example when using a composite key in a URL or in a HTML form widget, often introduces extra complexity.

Comment: The feature to introduce composite primary keys and foreign keys have been requested multiple times, and likely the database itself is not the hardest part, but the developer team keeps denying it, because it is not just the database, a lot of the rest of Django is built with the assumption that keys are singular, and therefore even if one manages to fix the ORM layer, it only will "delay the penalty".